# Sacar promedio en JavaScript de un array ubicado en un archivo JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hola a todos programadores, necesito sacar un promedio en JavaScript de un array ubicado en un archivo JSON el cual es la edad de los Super Heroes, intente con este codigo pero no me funciono. aun soy principiante.

```
var sumaEdad = superHeroes.members[i].age.reduce(function(acumulador, siguienteValor){
                return {
                    age: acumulador.age + siguienteValor.age};
                }, {age: 0});
            var promedioEdad = sumaEdad.age / superHeroes.length;
            document.write("El promedio es: " + promedioEdad);
```

Este es el archivo Json: [Enlace al archivo Json](https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json)

```
{
  "squadName" : "Super Hero Squad",
  "homeTown" : "Metro City",
  "formed" : 2016,
  "secretBase" : "Super tower",
  "active" : true,
  "members" : [
    {
      "name" : "Molecule Man",
      "age" : 29,
      "secretIdentity" : "Dan Jukes",
      "powers" : [
        "Radiation resistance",
        "Turning tiny",
        "Radiation blast"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "Madame Uppercut",
      "age" : 39,
      "secretIdentity" : "Jane Wilson",
      "powers" : [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "Eternal Flame",
      "age" : 1000000,
      "secretIdentity" : "Unknown",
      "powers" : [
        "Immortality",
        "Heat Immunity",
        "Inferno",
        "Teleportation",
        "Interdimensional travel"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Este es el codigo completo

```
        const consultaURL = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';
        const consulta = new XMLHttpRequest();
        consulta.open('GET', consultaURL);
        consulta.responseType = 'json';
        consulta.send();
        consulta.onload = function(){
            const superHeroes = consulta.response;

            var sumaEdad = superHeroes.members.age.reduce(function(acumulador, siguienteValor){
                return {
                    age: acumulador.age + siguienteValor.age};
                }, {age: 0});
            var promedioEdad = sumaEdad.age / superHeroes.length;

            document.write("El promedio es: " + promedioEdad);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui tienes otro metodo haciendo uso de `foreach` para recorrer el objeto, espero te sirva

```js
  const consultaURL = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';
    const consulta = new XMLHttpRequest();
    consulta.open('GET', consultaURL);
    consulta.responseType = 'json';
    consulta.send();
    consulta.onload = function(){
        const superHeroes = consulta.response;
        let age = 0;
        superHeroes.members.forEach(element => {
            age += element.age;
        });
        age = age/superHeroes.members.length
        document.write("El promedio es ",age);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*He modificado un poco tu código, te dejo el código funcional abajo*

```js
const consultaURL = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';
const consulta = new XMLHttpRequest();
consulta.open('GET', consultaURL);
consulta.responseType = 'json';
consulta.send();
consulta.onload = function() {
    const superHeroes = consulta.response;
    var sumaEdades = 0;
    for(var idx = 0; idx < superHeroes.members.length; idx++) {
        sumaEdades += superHeroes.members[idx].age;
        if (idx === superHeroes.members.length - 1) {
            var promedioEdad = sumaEdades/superHeroes.members.length;
            document.write("El promedio es: " + promedioEdad);
        }
    }
}
```

*Espero te sirva*

Answer (score 0):

La idea de usar `reduce` para sacar la suma de las edades es totalmente correcta y, de hecho, la mejor.
Pero primero debes extraer todas las edades de cada uno de los elementos del *array*. Para ello podemos usar `map`.

```
const getAges = members =>
  members.map(member => member.age);
```

Con ese resultado, hacer la suma.

```
const sumAges = ages =>
  ages.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);
```

Habiendo separado el problema en dos pasos se reduce la dificultad.

Te dejo aquí un ejemplo entero.

```js
const getAges = members =>
  members.map(member => member.age);

const sumAges = ages =>
  ages.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur);

const handle = response => {
  const members = response.members;
  const ages = getAges(members);
  const sum = sumAges(ages);

  console.log(members);                   // [(..), (..), (..)]
  console.log(ages);                      // [29, 39, 1000000]
  console.log(sum);                       // 1000068
  const average = sum / members.length;
  console.log(`Age average: ${average}`); // 333356
}

(async () => {
  const url = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';
  const req = await fetch(url);
  const res = await req.json();

  handle(res);
})();
```

Espero que sirva.